# Neatly merging multiple columns into several other columns

Tags: r

I've got a problem on how to neatly merge a lot of columns into less columns.
My df looks something like this (but with a lot more similar columns).

```
    df <- data.frame(
        A1 = c(1,1,1,NA,NA,NA),
        A2 = c(NA,NA,NA,1,1,1),
        B1 = c("text","text","text",NA,NA,NA),
        B2 = c(NA,NA,NA,"text","text","text")
    )
# which looks like this
A1    A2    B1      B2
1     NA    "text"  NA
1     NA    "text"  NA
1     NA    "text"  NA
NA    1     NA      "text"
NA    1     NA      "text"
NA    1     NA      "text"
```

I would like to merge all the A columns into one A column and all the B columns into a B column. Like this.

```
A      B
1    "text"
1    "text"
1    "text"
1    "text"
1    "text"
1    "text"
```

I am able to do this for one set of columns with this code:

```
df %<>% mutate(A1 = ifelse(is.na(A1), A2, A1))
# or possibly
df %<>% unite(A, A1, A2, sep = "", na.rm = TRUE) %>% mutate(A = as.numeric(A))
```

However, I have a lot of columns that need to be merged like this, resulting in a huge `mutate` command. Is there a way to do this cleaner/shorter?

Note: The names in the example are called A1 and A2 for clarity, in my orginal df, they are not that easily coupled.

Comment: How are the vars paired in your real data?  By position or by name? If by name can you give some examples that illustrate the logic of how they should be paired?  This info is key to solving your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no logic in how they should be paired. I can make lists of which two belong together, but that is done manually.

Comment: @Slaatje, I've [posted a possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65272259/1270695) that's not dependent on the original column names. Let me know if this is closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach... use a named `list` of column pairs and `fcoalesce` from "data.table". The names of the list will become the column names in the final `data.frame`.

```
pairs = list(A = 2:3, B = c(4, 6), C = c(5, 1))

data.frame(lapply(pairs, function(x) data.table::fcoalesce(df[x])))
#   A    B   C
# 1 1 text 1.2
# 2 1 text 1.2
# 3 1 text 1.2
# 4 1 text 1.2
# 5 1 text 1.2
# 6 1 text 1.2
```

Sample data used for this example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  C2 = c(1.2, NA, 1.2, 1.2, NA, NA), A1 = c(1,1,1,NA,NA,NA),
  A2 = c(NA,NA,NA,1,1,1), B1 = c("text","text","text",NA,NA,NA),
  C1 = c(NA, 1.2, NA, NA, 1.2, 1.2), B2 = c(NA,NA,NA,"text","text","text")
)

df
#    C2 A1 A2   B1  C1   B2
# 1 1.2  1 NA text  NA <NA>
# 2  NA  1 NA text 1.2 <NA>
# 3 1.2  1 NA text  NA <NA>
# 4 1.2 NA  1 <NA>  NA text
# 5  NA NA  1 <NA> 1.2 text
# 6  NA NA  1 <NA> 1.2 text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the base R code

```
unstack(
  transform(
    subset(u <- stack(df), complete.cases(u)),
    ind = gsub("\\d+$", "", ind)
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  A    B
1 1 text
2 1 text
3 1 text
4 1 text
5 1 text
6 1 text
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. As mentioned above, the names are not easily paired. Also, I have other variables that do not need to be paired, which are changed by the gsub.

Comment: @Slaatje Could you show a small example of your real data?

Comment: No sorry. privacy reasons. :( The variable names are something like Q2 and Q53 and there is no logic to the pairing. (see comment under original post)

Comment: @Slaatje If you don't have logic to pair columns, then I have no idea what the code should be written

Comment: No problem Thanks for giving it a try.